# Other site button -jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't event know what I would like to do should be called.... So I will explain it:

I have a website where there is a `<form>` that is generated and submitted using jquery. (Let's call it mywebsite.com).

To simplify, this form, let's say it only post a user email to a ASP.NET MVC4 controller.

I would like to have this  to be available on another site. The site of my partners. (hiswebsite.com)

How can I provide him with code snippet that would work for him too?

Scenario:

```
1. User click on button
2. A jQuery dialog shows up and ask for email.
3. The user clicks submit (POST)
4. The email is stored on mywebsite.com 
5. The dialog closes.
```

It's kind of a "Facebook login button"... It shows up the Facebook login dialog. Instead, I want the Enter Email Dialog from mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

I will create a script which will generate a  tag on the hosting web site. This tag will contain a  which will create a dialog containing an iFrame with src = mywebsite.com